# If $\tan^{-1}(x) + \tan^{-1} (y)+\tan^{-1} (z)=\pi$; then prove that $x+y+z=xyz$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove the above condition? I know how to prove it. To solve this question generally we take $x=y=z$. So, here in this question $x=y=z=\tan(\pi/3)$. But my question is that why we will take $x=y=z$? In the question it is not mentioned that $x=y=z$. There can be other possible values of $x,y,z$ also for which the above condition will be satisfied. Also it can be that $x\neq y\neq z$ or $x=y\neq z$, etc. because in the question it is not mentioned that all the three have to be equal. Please help me out.

Comment: Hint: $\tan(A + B + C) = \dfrac{\tan A + \tan B + \tan C - \tan A \tan B \tan C}{1 - \tan A \tan B - \tan B \tan C  - \tan C \tan A}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**:
$\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(y)+\tan^{-1}(z)= \pi \iff \tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(y)=\pi - \tan^{-1}(z)$.

$\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(y)=\begin{cases}\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy} \ \ \ (xy<1), \\
\pi + \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+y}{1-x} \ \ \ (x>0, \ xy>1),\\ 
-\pi + \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+y}{1-x} \ \ \ (x<0, \ xy>1).\end{cases}$

Comment: But how to approach further?

Comment: Can you find any other values of x,y,z other than x=y=z= tan(pi/3).

Comment: Apply hints from my answer, you will have $\tan^{-1}\tfrac{x+y}{1-xy}$on the left sides and $\pi - \tan^{-1} z$ on the right side. Hence, you can continue by taking $\tan$ on both sides....

Comment: @DEBSANKARROY there are infinite solutions to $x+y+z=xyz$ which ig you can easily figure out

Comment: Ok. I have understood.

Comment: Thank you very much @ Anton Vrdoljak.

Comment: You're welcome @DEBSANKARROY.